# SQL Исключить вывод где есть значения больше определенной даты

Tags: sql

Дана таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо найти все name, где в таблице отсутствуют записи date большее 2021-03-01 00:00

Вывести должен только nane = '12', тк для 10 и 11 присутствуют записи больше 2021-03-01 00:00

Comment: С чем у вас возникли сложности?

Answer (score 1):

Используем конструкцию `WHERE NOT EXISTS`

```
select name 
from tbl 
where not exists (
  select name from tbl tmp 
  where tmp.date > '2021-03-01 00:00' and tmp.name = tbl.name 
);
```

[Test SQL online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=c228d9ff7bbc7b8d23a1da05db375d16&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

```
select tbl.name 
from tbl 
left join tbl tmp on tmp.date > '2021-03-01 00:00' and tmp.name = tbl.name 
where tmp.name is null;
```

Comment: без exists ни как?

Comment: @NMD, да, ответ обновлен

Comment: @NMD, а чем exists не устраивает?

Answer (score 0):

```
select name
from table1
group by name
having max(date) <= '2021-03-01 00:00'
```

Для каждого имени находим максимальную дату, и выкидываем те, у кого она больше заданной